# Tried to validate my page, I have an error on my <script> tag, missing attribute?

Tags: javascript, validation

```
Line 207, Column 50: Required attributes missing on element script.

   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

Element-specific attributes for element script:
    Global attributes
    src
    async
    defer
    type
    charset
```

What is it that I am missing?
Thankyou

Edit: This is for all of my handwritten code, I don't want it connecting to an external js file

Comment: Can you please post the complete section or give us an example page?

Comment: cat - You can post your own solution as an answer as well.

Comment: The validator would have told me if there was an error with my javascript. I found how to fix it I answered in a comment below

Answer (score 0):

Seams legit. Maybe something to do with what you have **inside** the `<script>`?

> [**Content model**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html):
>    If there is no src
>   attribute, depends on the value of the
>   type attribute, but must match script
>   content restrictions.

Comment: Ahh I solved it. I just had to remove the charset attribute... I don't understand why! :) 

Thanks though

Comment: @cat: You should have posted this as an **answer**. In HTML5 you can by the way also omit the `type` attribute. It implicitly defaults to `text/javascript` then.

Answer (score 0):

See this piece of the [XHTML strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd)

```
<!ELEMENT script (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST script
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED
  xml:space   (preserve)     #FIXED 'preserve'
  >
```

The only required attribute is `type`. The problem lies in another part of your code, please paste it here.

Comment: It's validating now, no errors or warnings. Maybe because it was checked as html5? I don't know, seems perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me..
This document was successfully checked as HTML 4.0 Transitional!

Answer (score 0):

To fix it all I had to do was remove the charset attribute. :)